# Column(index).Search() not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to apply a filter menu on a specific column in a jquery datatable. When I have a list of hard-coded data in a table, and I apply the filter on a specific column, the filtering works. But when I get the data from the server side, and the processing is on server side, the filtering does not work on a specific column. But the filtering works only on the table as a whole. I have the following code-snippet:

```
    var empTable = $("#employeetable").DataTable({

        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Employee/GetList",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Name", "name": "Name" },
            { "data": "Position", "name": "Position" },
            { "data": "Office", "name": "Office" },
            { "data": "Age", "name": "Age" },
            { "data": "Salary", "name": "Salary" },
        ],

        "serverSide": "true",
        "order": [0, "asc"],
        "processing": "true",
        "language": {
            "processing": "processing... please wait"
        }
    });

  $('#table-filter2').on('change', function () {
            console.log(this.value);
            empTable.column(1).search(this.value).draw();
        });
```

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Didn't you ask a very similar question about 1 hour ago?

Comment: Asking again in a better way to get a prompt answer.

Comment: When it is added by `AJAX` you want a delegated event handler. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @jones Did you think about editing you previously question so it was more clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search().Column() not working on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892183/search-column-not-working-on-server-side)

Comment: I think its not getting the column index right. Any help on this ?

Comment: Needed a solution to this . Facing the same problem